# Raspberry Pi SW-420 vibration sensor and Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, vibration

I'm trying to create an application that will sense my laundry machine turning on. Then when it's done, i want it to detect that and flash my Hue bulbs. I'm using the SW-420 vibration sensor and Python for this project. I have successfully gotten it to recognize vibration, but unfortunately, it's not what I need. The following is my current code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import subprocess

#GPIO SETUP
channel = 17
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN)

def start(channel):
    if GPIO.input(channel):
        print "Dryer has started!"
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print "Dryer has stopped" 
        time.sleep(1)
        #f = open("status", "w") #Used to create light status file
        #subprocess.call(["perl", "/home/pi/huepi/huepi", "lights"], stdout=f); # creates status file
        #subprocess.call(["perl", "/home/pi/huepi/huepi", "for", "1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12", "do", "blinkonce"]); # blinks hue bulbs 

GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.BOTH, bouncetime=300)  # let us know when the pin goes HIGH or LOW
GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, start)  # assign function to GPIO PIN, Run function on change

# infinite loop
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

The issue that I'm having is even when the machine is running the sensor registers that it has stopped. I've tried using

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING, bouncetime=300)
```

and

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.FALLING, bouncetime=300)
```

both with the same results. I just need it to register that the machine has started then with it stops flash the Hue bulb and wait for the next time the machine starts back up.

I'm using a Perl library called Huepl to interface with but bulbs That section of the code is working fine. If you need any more information I'll be glad to supply. Thank you in advance!

Comment: please fix your indentation. thats part of the python code structure

Comment: Put a hand on your dryer. Its shaking all the time while running, you need to detect when it switches from "not vibrating" to "vibrating" and then when it is still for > 60 seconds or so. thats how I would try to tackle it.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I have corrected the indentations in the code block. My file had those already. I must have just missed them when adding them to this post. I'm not exactly sure how to accomplish having it detect when its still for 60 seconds or so. Would you mind explaining in more detail?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Would I use something like this?

    Channel = GPIO.wait_for_edge(channel, GPIO_RISING, timeout=60000)
    if channel is None:
        #######
    else:
        #######

Answer (score 0):

Set `started` via callback on your first detected vibration. Set a `lastShakeTime` to now via callback whenever you detect vibration.

In your main loop check if nothing was detected for 60s:

```
import datetime

# infinite loop
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if started and (now - lastShakeTime).total_seconds() > 60:
        # do something with your oleds
```

Polling vs. Eventbased: 
    https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/